# VTCompressionSession Bitrate/Datarate overshooting

Tags: ios, macos, compression, h.264, video-toolbox

I have been working on an *H264 hardware accelerated encoder* implementation using VideoToolbox's `VTCompressionSession` for a while now, and a consistent problem has been the unreliable bitrate coming out of it. I have read many forum posts and looked through existing code for this, and tried to follow suit, but the bitrate out of my encoder is almost always somewhere between 5% and 50% off what it is set at, and on occasion I've seen some huge errors, like even 400% overshoot, where even one frame will be twice the size of the given average bitrate.

My session is setup as follows:

- `kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AverageBitRate` = desired bitrate
- `kVTCompressionPropertyKey_DataRateLimits` = [desired bitrate / 8, 1]; accounting for bits vs bytes
- `kVTCompressionPropertyKey_ExpectedFrameRate` = framerate (30, 15, 5, or 1 fps)
- `kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxKeyFrameInterval` = 1500
- `kVTCompressionPropertyKey_MaxKeyFrameIntervalDuration` = 1500 / framerate
- `kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AllowFrameReordering` = NO
- `kVTCompressionPropertyKey_ProfileLevel`  = `kVTProfileLevel_H264_Main_AutoLevel`
- `kVTCompressionPropertyKey_RealTime` = YES
- `kVTCompressionPropertyKey_H264EntropyMode` = `kVTH264EntropyMode_CABAC`
- `kVTCompressionPropertyKey_BaseLayerFrameRate` = framerate / 2

And I adjust the average bitrate and datarate values throughout the session to try and compensate for the volatility (if it's too high, I reduce them a bit, if too low, I increase them, with restrictions on how high and low to go).
I create the session and then apply the above configuration as a single dictionary using `VTSessionSetProperties` and feed frames into it like this:

`VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame(compressionSessionRef,
                                 static_cast<CVImageBufferRef<(pixelBuffer),
                                 CMTimeMake(capturetime, 1000),
                                 kCMTimeInvalid,
                                 frameProperties,
                                 frameDetailsStruct,
                                 &encodeInfoFlags);`

So I'm supplying timing information as the API says to do.
Then I add up the size of the output for each frame and divide over a periodic time period, to determine the outgoing bitrate and error from desired. This is where I see the significant volatility.

I'm looking for any help in getting the bitrate under control, as I'm not sure what to do at this point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check the frameTimestamp set in VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame, it seems affects the bitrate. If you change frame rate, change the frameTimestamp.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but can you please clarify what I should be checking about the `presentationTimeStamp` (I assume that's the parameter you're talking about)? I am updating that with every frame using `CMTimeMake(captureTime, 1000)`. I am also not changing the frames per second during an encoding session.

Comment: Use CMTimeMake(totalFrameCount, $frameRate)

Comment: Thank you, but I tried that and it didn't seem to change the result. Sometimes the encoder will spike up even 100% over what the target bitrate is.